# How to use Typescript as compiler in node-migrate

Tags: node.js, typescript, database-migration

To start, here's my migration script:

```
const bluebird = require("bluebird");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = bluebird;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/app", { useMongoClient: true    });

const schema = {    
    uid: {  
        type: String,   
    },  

    parentID: { 
        type: String,   
    },  

    name: { 
        type: String,   
    },  

    displayName: {  
        type: String,   
    },  

    createdAt: {    
        type: Date, 
    },  

    modifiedAt: {   
        type: Date, 
    }   
};  

const FolderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(schema);   
const FolderModel = mongoose.model("folders", FolderSchema);    


// initial folders  
const folders = [   
    { uid: "", parentID: "", name: "folder1", displayName: "Folder 1" },    
    { uid: "", parentID: "", name: "folder2", displayName: "Folder 2" },    
];  

function up(next) { 
    const promises = [];    
    folders.map((folder, index) => {    
        promises.push(FolderModel.create(folder));  
    }); 

    bluebird.all(promises).then((res) => {  
        mongoose.connection.close();    
        next(); 
    }); 
}   

function down(next) {   
    const promises = [];    
    folders.map((folder, index) => {    
        promises.push(FolderModel.remove({ name: folder.name }));   
    }); 

    bluebird.all(promises).then((res) => {  
        next(); 
    }); 
}   

module.exports.up = up;
module.exports.down = down;
```

I'm using [node-migrate](https://github.com/tj/node-migrate) for migration and in the Advanced migration creation part, it says:

Lastly, if you want to use newer ECMAscript features, or language addons like TypeScript,
for your migrations, you can use the compiler flag.

But when I run the the script with *--compiler="ts:typescript"* it always throw an error even though I already have typescript installed.

```
    C:\Users\john\Workspace\app\node_modules\migrate\lib\register-compiler.js:12
  require(mod)({
              ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at registerCompiler (C:\Users\john\Workspace\app\node_modules\migrate\lib\register-compiler.js:12:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\john\Workspace\app\node_modules\migrate\bin\migrate-up:57:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: Did you try: `--compiler="ts:tsc"`?

Comment: Hi @FaizuddinMohammed, I just tried your suggestion but it's not working. Anyway thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 10):

You can do the following to make `ts-node` work with `node-migrate`.

1. Create a simple js file, containing:

   ```
   const tsNode = require('ts-node');

   module.exports = tsNode.register;
   ```
2. Pass the compiler flag with the above file when executing a migration:

   `migrate up --compiler="ts:./typescript-compiler.js"`

This should be enough for you to run TypeScript migrations.

Answer (score 4):

Install `ts-node` and `typescript`.

```
npm install --save-dev ts-node typescript

# or

yarn add --dev ts-node typescript
```

Afterwards, set the compiler flag to the following:

```
--compiler="ts:ts-node/register"
```

---

I suppose the value in the flag `ts:typescript`, when split into its components--as delimited by the `:` character--in your original attempt represents the following:

- `ts`: the file extension
- `typescript`: the module that will register a new extension and language to load

The reason why `ts:typescript` does not work, is because you are telling `node-migrate` to `require` a module `typescript` to be used as what will register the TypeScript compiler as a module loader. However, `require`ing the `typescript` module does not register a new import logic for novel file extensions and languages.

In order to be able to `require` TypeScript files (novel file extensions and languages), you need to register the appropriate loader. `typescript` is the not the appropriate loader. However, `ts-node/register` definitely is.

Comment: Hi @Salehen, I tried your suggestion. So I changed the command to `node_modules\.bin\migrate up --clean --state-file=".\src\migrations\.migrate" --migrations-dir=".\src\migrations" --compiler="ts:ts-node/register"` but it still gives me the same error.

I have installed ts-node and typescript.

`"ts-node": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.0"`

Comment: OMG you saved my life ! I am so grateful ! Thank You so much !

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as of Oct 2022, using `ts-node` 10.4.0. Instead, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53282085/323177 seems to be the working solution