# Windows 10: No Found Typescript as compiler in node-migrate

Tags: node.js, typescript, windows-10, migration, package.json

I configured the migrations using [node-migrate](https://github.com/tj/node-migrate) and scripts layer to run a dummy migration and test all the functionality.

The project is in typescript and I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53282085/8112431) to adapt the compiler to the project, however, in Windows10 it fails

`npm run migration:run`

The error says that the compile module is not found

```sh
> migrate --store='./scripts/migrations-store.ts' --compiler='ts:./scripts/compiler.js' --matches '**/!(migration.example)*.ts' "up"

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'scripts/compiler.js''
Require stack:
...
```

I try many things and doesn't work. When I run this command in a UNIX s.o it works perfectly.

This is part of the package.json

```json
"scripts": {
 ...
 "migration": "migrate --store='./scripts/migrations-store.ts' --compiler='ts:./scripts/compiler.js' --matches '**/!(migration.example)*.ts'",
 "migration:create": "migrate create --template-file ./migrations/migration.example.ts",
 "migration:run": "npm run migration up",
 "migration:down": "npm run migration down"
}
```

Is there any way to make it work correctly for each team member regardless of the operating system?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696920/configuring-package-json-on-windows), but unfortunately, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to make everything work independent of the operating system, at least from windows, was to install [Windows Subsystem for Linux WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). then I updated the vscode configuration to use wsl2 and that was it! everything worked.

[image]